# Magento : How Display Category name in magento menu in two lines?

Tags: magento, menu, categories

I am working with magento 1.7 and i have many long categories name in my site. I wish to split every long category name in two line in menu because i would like to display my menu in one row and not two. Any idea ??? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different options for this. You can adjust the style of the category menu's div to contain:

```
.nav-menu-whatever {width:80px; word-wrap:break-word;}
```

But word-wrap may not work in all browsers.

Alternately, you can modify your category names in the admin to contain [zero-width spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_Width_Space) at strategic intervals. This will allow the category names to break where you want them too. Here's an example:

```
LONGTEXTLONGTEXTLONGTEXT&#8203;LONGTEXTLONGTEXTLONGTEXT&#8203;LONGTEXTLONG
```

Comment: I used &#8203; method and it's work.                                It help me for others problems. Tanks :)